# What are the primary reasons that customers don't purchase AB Testing services?

Tags: ab-testing, customer

I work in a UX consulting agency. I noticed while customers are happy to pay good money for our research and design services, AB testing and other post-launch services are seldom being asked for.

1. What are the common reasons for this?
2. What do you do to help your clients see the value of post-launch UX services?

Comment: There are many inexpensive A/B testing services available. Integrating them with a production web site is easy. Setting up, running, and analyzing a test is easy. It's possible your customers do not need your UX consulting agency to run an A/B test.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have the answer in your question. To me, AB-Testing isn't a post-launch service only. In fact we use it prior to launch to evaluate different patterns. If you use AB-Testing as a part of the UX design and evaluation, your customers would probably see the value of it.

The other not selling post-services is really a marketing issue and I can only guess what's wrong.

Comment: Well said. I did read "post launch" and thought it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

1. **Price** - some platforms cost in the 100k range. The cheaper DIY solutions are often slow, and too beginner.
2. **Build it ourselves** - some companies IT would prefer to build in-house instead of using 3rd party tools and going through laborious procurement processes. When you show them the many benefits and efficiencies by using a 3rd party tool it becomes easier to understand why IT should not reinvent the wheel.
3. **Ownership** - If it's no ones job to do A/B testing it's hard to push that initiative, especially if you are already busy with work. Chances are if someone at the company believed in testing they would already have someone doing it or dedicate a role to that purpose. Many companies have role dedicated to a/b testing and personalization.
4. **disbelief** - this one is dumb, but some people just don't believe in science :)